# Unit of android.graphics.Camera#getLocationZ()

Tags: android, graphics, 3d, android-canvas

About **Unit:**

I'm not a native english speaker, correct me if I use a wrong word. We know that numbers like `1, 3.48` are just numbers, but when they're followed by `cm`, `px`, they represent distance. `cm` and `px` is what I call **Unit**.

**My Question:**

`Camera#getLocationZ()` returns a float value which represents the z location of the camera. But the documentation doesn't tell what its unit is, and default is -8. One blog says that it's equals to **-8×72** pixels, that is, **1 represents 72 pixels**. So the unit must not be `px`.

So, what's the unit the location uses?

Thanks for your answer.

---

If you vote down this question, please let me know the reason. Or you can ask me to edit my answer to add more descriptions.

Comment: return float value.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya But what's the unit? Apparently **it's not px**.